# Time series feature extraction using Fourier transformation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, time-series, fft

The dataset of `921rows` x `10166columns` is used to prediction bacteria plate count based on water temperature. Each row is an observation(first 10080 columns being the time series of water temperature and the remaining 2 columns being y labels- 1 means high bacteria count, 0 means low bacteria count).

There is fluctuation in the temperature for each activation. For the rest of the time, water temperature would remain constant at 25°C. Since there are too many features in the time series, I am thinking about extracting some relevant features from the time series data, such as the first 3 lowest frequency values or amplitude of the time series using `fft`or `ifft`etc from`scipy.fftpack`, then fit into a logistics regression model. However, due to limited background knowledge in waves/signal, I am confused about a few things:

1)Does applying `fft` on the time series produce an array of numbers of the frequencies of the time series data? If not, which function should I use instead?

2)I've done `forward fill` to my time series data(ie. data points are spaced at fixed time intervals) and the number of data for each time series is the same. If 1) is correct, will the number of frequencies returned for different time series be the same?

Below is a basic visualisation of my original data.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Instead of getting frequency and amplitude, did you try the extraction of the variance and standard deviation?

Comment: @Noki I did in a neural network model and the first 4 moments didn't seem to contribute but rather impact the model negatively. Not sure if they might behave differently in a simple logistics regression model though.

Comment: Did you try different window sizes when extracting the features (maybe you need bigger windows)? Also, I would try more models, not only neural nets.

Comment: I don't think spectral methods are meaningful here, unless you have some periodic lab temperature fluctuation (days/nights, weekends). But that you would plot as temperature over time, or bacterial population over time (to get at parameters other than temperature, say someone turns a fan on Mo - Fr that lowers the humidity). What you likely want is a plot for the bacteria populations vs the temperature.  Note:In your graph it is not labelled what the y-axis actually is.

Comment: @roadrunner66 Thanks for the reply. The graph is about temperature over time. A plot for the bacteria populations vs the temperature is preferable but unfortunately not available as there is only one bacteria count data for each observation for most cases. That is why I hope to extract some insightful features from the times series.

Comment: @Noki Thanks for your suggestion. Sorry I am not familiar with the concept.. Could you please elaborate a bit more on the window size idea or do you know of any relevant materials? Thank you

Comment: You have three columns (temp, bac count high, bact. count low). For each temperature interval you could count the times that the the bacterial counts was high as a fraction of measurements at that temperature interval.

Comment: @roadrunner66 Thank you for your comment. There seems to be some misunderstanding here. The temperature data is of time series format of 10000 data point for each row. At the end of each row, there is one pair of one-hot labelling representing high/low bacteria level(ie. 10000 columns rather than 1 column for temp, plus 2 columns for bac count high, bact. count low). Would I be able to apply the time interval idea here? Thanks

Comment: In that case I'd integrate the temperature for each row (equivalent to average temp. ) and set a 1 for high and a 0 for the low count. You get 921 data points, but unfortunately only one category for y (0 or 1). So that plot won't be so interesting. So now you could make say 10 intervals for the different average temps and plot the ratio of high/low counts for each interval. Later you could repeat that with other measures for the temps, say max, median rather than average.

Comment: The point being that the bacteria count is a measure for the integrated exposure to warmth, but your temperature is a time series.  There could also be temperatures (very high) that impede the growth or even kill off bacteria, so you could overlay the average data with the max data.

Comment: @roadrunner66 The max temp idea sounds very relevant- I will give it a try; my only concern is that max temp may be similar for all observations given the similar conditions for all observations , and average temp may overlook some deeper and more insightful pattern underlying the time series as it is only a point estimate. That's why I resort to frequency/amplitude of the time series data, which hopefully summarise the overall characteristics of the time series. Any thought on that? Thanks

Comment: You could make it more interesting with a model for the bacteria, that (exponentially) grows them faster each time it's hot and stops growth below a certain temperature, but I don't think that would imply applicability of spectral analysis (FFT) either, since the FFT is linear, but your growth at each time step is nonlinear (as it depends on the amount of bacteria just before the time step).

Comment: @roadrunner66 I will try to do that. Thanks for your advice:)